# Select row in dataframe with column more than 1 values

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have this dataframe :

```
A            Variant&Price                Qty
AAC           7:124|25: 443                1
AAD             35:|35:                    1
AAS           32:98|3:40                   1
AAG             2: |25:                    1
AAC          25:443|26:344                 1
```

And I want to select row which has type 7 and below, so then my dataframe will look like this

```
A            Variant&Price                 Qty
AAC           7:124|25: 443                1
AAS            32:9|3:40                   1
AAG             2: |25:                    1
```

`:` is separator between type and price, `12:250` means type 12 with price 250. `|` is separator of item. I dont know how to deal with column with more than one value. I am trying to change its type to string but then how do I select 7 and below ? also the data that w are interested is only one digit before `:` and one digit after `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` method is very useful in your case: like that we can split the type/price column into 4 parts. Then we take the minimum elements from first and third parts (the types) and if it is lower than 7, we take it in our final result.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([['AAC', '7:124|25:443', 1],
                ['AAD', '35:|35:', 1],
                ['AAS', '32:98|3:40', 1],
                ['AAG', '2: |25: ', 1],
                ['AAC', '25:443|26:344', 1]],
               columns=['A', 'Variant&Price', 'Qty'])

split_df = df['Variant&Price'].str.split(':|\|', expand=True)
print(df[split_df.iloc[:, [0,2]].astype(int).min(axis=1) <= 7])
```

Comment: how if I want to put between 2 until 7 ? I cannt put >=2 & <=7

Comment: You can extract the types, apply the method between on both and then use the operator |  :

types_1 = split_df.iloc[:, 0].astype(int)
types_2 = split_df.iloc[:, 2].astype(int)
print(df[types_1.between(2, 7) | types_2.between(2, 7)])